# How do I get rid of the extra options on a pinned program on the start menu

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, start-menu, pinning

In Windows 7 when I pin certain programs, somehow there is something that allows them to have a sub menu.  Examples of this are both Firefox (Enter private browsing) and Chrome (New window, New incognito window).

For some reason on some machines I don't see this, and on others I do.  I tend to not like having these extra options - how do I disable this from showing up for pinned programs and just have it be a shortcut.

Comment: I didn't think you can - this is a new feature of Windows 7. However, it is a new feature of Firefox - Chrome has supported it for some time. Are you sure that both machines are running the same versions of these programs?

Comment: They are.. chrome always auto updates and I'm using the same branch (stable).  One shows options, one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox specifically it is a new feature. I am running 3.6.10 and I do not have these options, but when I run Firefox 4 Beta 5+ I do have these options.  I believe these options are handled on a per application basis.  As far as I know there are no options to disable these context menu options.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox - as usual - can be tweaked to suit your preferences. For the taskbar options go to about:config in Firefox and search for: "browser.taskbar ...." In particular:

- To disable the tasks options, search for `browser.taskbar.lists.tasks.enabled` and toggle its value to `false`
- To disable the frequent list, go to:  `browser.taskbar.lists.frequent.enabled` and toggle its value to `false`

Other options for the taskbar are also available and the names in `about:config` (`browser.taskbar`...) should be explanatory enough. See here for more info: [Firefox 4 tips for Windows 7 users](http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2011/04/firefox-4-tips-for-windows-7-users/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Firefox and Chrome are adding them.

You might as well be asking:

> How can i remove the New Tab menu option in Chrome?

You can't. Having menu's is a feature of Windows, that Chrome and Firefox take advantage of. Windows cannot override what an application does.

Having items in a pin menu is a feature of Windows, that Chrome and Firefox take advantage of. Windows cannot override what an application does.

Some people don't like toolbars either.

Comment: I have Windows 7 installed on 2 machines, on one Chrome has the sub menu and on one it doesn't.  Same Windows and Chrome versions.

Comment: Then i would ask for the version numbers of both. i would also suggest that if one Chome is not showing the "New Tab" option on some machines: it's a bug that you should report.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not have the option to disable like Firefox. However here is a workaround:

1. Start
2. Right click All Programs, Open
3. Right click, New, Shortcut
4. For location, put your home page, for example

   ```
   http://example.com
   ```
5. Pin this new shortcut and you are good to go